# Custom component Convertion from delphi 5 to delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-5

Recently I got a chance to convert `delphi-5` code to `delphi-7`. At first I started converting Custom components to `delphi-7`. While compiling `delphi-5` components in `delphi-7` system is throwing error stating

> "Undeclared identifier: IFormDesigner".

After googling I came to know `IFormDesigner` should be replaced with `IDesigner`. So after replacing `IFormDesigner` with `IDesigner` and separating design code from runtime code, most of the components got compiled. While compiling below piece of code it is getting compiled successfully. but when I place the component on form system is throwing access violation error at

> Path:=IDesigner(TForm(FFormOwner).Designer).GetPrivateDirectory in
>   delphi7.

Below is my component code.

```
constructor TsampleComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FFormOwner:=TForm(Owner);
  if not (Owner is TForm) then
    repeat
      FFormOwner:=TForm(FFormOwner.Owner);
    until (FFormOwner is TForm) or (FFormOwner.Owner=nil);

  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    //Path:=IFormDesigner(TForm(FFormOwner).Designer).GetPrivateDirectory--     delphi 5 code
    Path:=IDesigner(TForm(FFormOwner).Designer).GetPrivateDirectory
  else
    Path:=ExtractFilePath(Application.EXEName);
.
.

end;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you mix AOwner, Owner and FFomrOwner? Where is Owner from? What is the repeat loop for?

Comment: `Designer` is an interface of type `IDesignerHook`. If it supports `IFormDesigner` you'll be able to get there with an `as` cast. In fact you should be using checked casts so that you observe meaningful errors. Try `((FFormOwner as TForm).Designer) as IFormDesigner`. I don't know the ins and outs of these interfaces but I do know that using unchecked casts leaves you clueless when they go wrong. Let the type system help you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you. Working Code: `(((FFormOwner as TForm).Designer) as IDesigner).GetPrivateDirectory`.        i have another question which i have asked seperately [TypeCasting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637832/typecasting-what-is-difference-between-below-2-lines-of-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Designer` property is of type `IDesignerHook` and cannot be hard cast to `IDesigner`. To have any hope of success you would need code of this form:

```
(FFormOwner as TForm).Designer as IDesigner
```

This will perform a runtime query of the `IDesignerHook` interface `Designer`, and return an `IDesigner` interface if that interface is indeed supported.